# Connect MySql to a machine on the same network

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to connect a machine script **X** to a database on the machine **Y**.
I can handle the bank perfectly on the machine **Y**, but when I run the machine **X** I get the error below:

```
"2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.22.128.1:3306 (10060)"
```

Below my connection script inserted into the machine **Y**

```
declaracao = f'INSERT INTO similares (momento,produto1,produto2,res) VALUES ("teste","teste","teste",10.00);'

try:
#CREATE CONNECTION MYSQL
   con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', host='172.22.128.1', database='saneamento') #Here where to return the error

   cursor = con.cursor()
   cursor.execute(declaracao)
   con.commit()
   print(cursor.rowcount, "Insert dados!")
   cursor.close()

 except Error as e:
   print("Fail", e)
```

Below computer IP **X**

```
Adress IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 172.22.128.1
```

[Settings XAMPP:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYaie.png)

[Settings MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjNlY.png)

[Settings phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XYar.png)

*Computers X and Y are on the same network*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you manually connect to your MySQL database from a remote server?

```sql
remote linux server> mysql -D <database> -h <host> -u <user> -p -e "<mysql command>"
```

If that fails, you should check that MySQL will allow the root user to connect from a remote host.  You might have it setup with a root@localhost entry, but not a root@<remote host> entry.

```sql
  mysql> select * from mysql.user;
```

If you only have a localhost entry for root, you can do this on Linux to add a remote host entry.

```sql
  mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'remote_server_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

  mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database_name>.* TO 'root'@'remote_server_ip' WITH GRANT OPTION;

  mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

** Note that you can replace 'remote_server_ip' with '%' to allow access from any remote server.

If it still doesn't work, you might need to check your firewall.